# Remove all previous css styles

Tags: html, css

I've a javscript package which create a popup. I also have some css styles for that popup. Users can import the script (and the css) either using npm or using a cdn.

The problem is that sometimes these styles are overridden by the website's style. For example like this

```
 a {
   text-decoration: none !important;
 }
```

I don't want any other styles to be applied on that popup from the website, how can I achieve this?

Comment: create your `popup` as a custom-component and incorporate its styles within its ShadowDom - that would isolate them from outside interference as it were

Comment: You can use [CSS layers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer) as major support is just around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is, when you see shoddy CSS scripting like this (adding an !important property on a fundamental tag), go around the developer that made it and find yourself a better developer.

That said, it is possible to override the !important property by using the same or a higher hierarchical identifier and use the !important property on that too. As your CSS loads later in time than the standard CSS script does, your CSS gets a preference because of the cascading character of CSS.

The website's style:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Your custom style:

```
a {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

Please consider the fact that there is a hierarchy in the specification of identifiers in CSS. You can read more about this on the W3 schools website: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Comment: Hi, The thing is I can't possibly know which styles have !important tags on it. As the popup is used by different sites. Some have this !important style, while others can have :after/:before on a global selector like this ```body h2:before {content: ""}```. So I can't possibly predict which styles should have !important. I just want to remove (or not applied) and styles other then the one I'm specifying.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It is the other way around as I can see now. You should try Professor Abronsius' solution. You can find more about this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM